# Angular with Azure Durable Functions => retryWhen for http response

Tags: angular, azure, rxjs, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to use Azure Functions form Angular 10 application.
The trick is to hide the complexity of Azure function protocol behind single Observable.

To call Azure function I need to do the following:

- Send POST request to the Azure function URL to start back office processing.
- In the response I get the URL to pool for response.
- Starts polling the URL and check the status field in the response (when set to Running or Processing that means the result is not available yet)
- At some point the response is going to give the result back.

So I am looking for an ability to retry the GET call asynchronously like retryWhen operator does but instead of monitoring the errors it should be looking into the response itself and retry the operation until the status field in response is set to completed.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you man poll?

Comment: yes, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
data$ = initialPost().pipe(
   switchMap(postData => pollRequest(postData.url).pipe(
      expand(pollData => pollData.status === 'in progress' ? pollRequest(postData.url) : EMPTY)
   )
);
```

expand operator will return events from the emmiting observable back to the same callback untill they are over. if some "timeout" or any other timing logic is required between polling calls then just feel free to modify the observable that is returned from expand